# How to write EXPECT_CALL for the mock function with return type std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> in gtest/gmock

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector, googletest, googlemock

I have a member function in the c++ class with return type `std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>>`

**************code.cpp**************

```
class A
{
A();
~A();
std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> function();

};
```

************AMock.cpp**************

```
using vectorOfTuple= std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>>;
Class A_mock
{
MOCK_METHOD(vectorOfTuple, function, (),());
};
```

***********ATest.cpp*******************

```
TEST_F(TestClass, testname)
{
using vectorOfTuple= std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>>;
vectorOfTuple result;
vectorOfTuple getAllValues = {{10,2},
    {20,2},
    {30,2},
    {40,2}
    };
 EXPECT_CALL(A_mock, function())
            .WillRepeatedly(DoAll(
                SetArrayArgument<0>(getAllValues.begin(),
                                    getAllValues.end()),
                SetArgPointee<1>(getAllValues.size()),
                Return(result)));
}
```

***********PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**********************

1. I am getting the error: external/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:125:41: error: no matching function for call to 'get<0>(const args_type&)'
   ::std::copy(first, last, ::std::get(args));
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
2. How to get all the values of VectorOfTuple to the result variable?

**********Please Note*******************

1. Please refer ATest.cpp first
2. All the code is just for example/reference to explain the scenario, please do not concentrate on any other errors

Comment: `SetArrayArgument` is to fill **output** arguments. your function doesn't have argument...

Comment: `Return(result)` -> `Return(getAllValues)` (and get rid of `DoAll`, `SetArrayArgument` and `SetArgPointee`).

Comment: When you read the tag [gmock] description, have you seen *Gmock is a mocking framework for Groovy. For questions relating to Google Mock, use tag [googlemock] instead.*? Why then have you used the wrong tag?